# Regex modifier to treat the pattern as a fixed string

Tags: regex

I usually have 'Regular expression' as the default search mode in Notepad++, and I was looking for a way to avoid changing the search modes between 'Normal' and 'Regular expression' all the time, based on the type of pattern I'm searching for.

Is there any modifier in regex to treat any pattern (part or whole) as a fixed string? For example, I want `test_group="${test_group}"` to be matched as a literal string, without having to escape anything.

I found a modifier, `(?q)`, for Tcl [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), but I need something more general, that would work in searches in Notepad++/Vim, and preferably, something that even works in languages such as Perl/Java.

Comment: You can use `\Q` and `\E` to escape the whole content between.

Comment: From [tag:regex] tag page: "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool." There is no single answer. For instance, `\Q...\E` does not apply to Vim, nor Ruby or JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\Q and \E` to avoid escaping of characters inside match string

Example: to match `.${hello}` literally

```
\Q.${hello}\E
```

See [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK6xH9/1)